# How to prevent notifyDataSetChanged from collapsing open groups in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In my application I have a dynamic ExpandableListView along with a refresh button. When the user clicks on the refresh button, the latest data is downloaded and I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in order to update the UI.

The problem is that notifyDataSetChanged() collapses all the groups that were previously open which leads to a bad experience for the user. Is there a way that this can be avoided?

Thanks

Comment: We need more info please.  What adapter are you using? If it's custom can you post it's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my method that I use. `setExpandedGroup()` before update your `UI`, then `getExpandedIds()` after update. Also my `idsExpand = new ArrayList<Integer>()` is `Integer` array.

```
public static void setExpandedGroup() {
        if (expListView != null
                && expListView.getExpandableListAdapter() != null) {
            final int groupCount = expListView.getExpandableListAdapter().getGroupCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++) {
                if (expListView.isGroupExpanded(i)) {
                    idsExpand.add(i);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void getExpandedIds() {
        if (idsExpand != null) {
            final int groupCount = idsExpand.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++) {
                if (expListView != null) {
                    try {
                        expListView.expandGroup(idsExpand.get(i));
                    } catch (Exception ignored) {
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Where exactly do you call these? I tried something similar but in getGroupView(), isExpanded is already set to false

Comment: You should load it in Fragment / Activity, but not in adapter.

Comment: This is incorrect.  The `ExpandableListView` and it's adapter support re-expanding the groups when `notifyDataSetChanged()` is invoked.